# How to change default insertion of date format in mysql to d M yy?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Here's my date format using to insert into database and in front end also displaying same.
But I want to change in front end like d M yy format.

```
$postedon = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->input->post('postedon')));
```

output is `Posted on : 2014-06-01`

Here date is inserting and displaying like 2014-06-01....
but, if I change date format like this

```
$postedon = date('d M yy',strtotime($this->input->post('postedon')));
```

it is inserting as 0000-00-00.

So please guide me how to change format of date.

Comment: You can't change the standard date format in mysql, why don't you just convert/format it whenever you need to display it ?

Comment: change your db field type date to varchar, but not a good idea you going

Comment: @RakeshSharma If change date as varchar then `order by` do not work on date

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change MySQL date format for database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052862/how-to-change-mysql-date-format-for-database)

Comment: i think formatted date like this doesn't insert in date field so result will be 0000-00-00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build two functions for date, to store in database and to display

here's the example

```
function us_date_formate_To_mysql($date){
    $date = str_replace("'", "", $date);
    $date = explode("/",$date);
    return $date = $date[2]."-".$date[0]."-".$date[1];
}
```

Arrange date as you want to show or save in your system.

Hope this will work for you.