# How can I change the MySQL date format?

Tags: mysql, date, format, mariadb

I am running a local MariaDB server via XAMPP. I have ~1000 LOC, which look like the following:

```
insert into jobs values(781,'13-01-2005',10006,1,2.5,1,4.00);
```

As I am using a european date format I keep getting the error:

```
Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '13-01-2005'
```

Is there any possibility to modify the date format, the database is using so that it will accept 'DD-MM-YYYY' as an input?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The format is static, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052862/how-to-change-mysql-date-format-for-database

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it with a little trick.

**1) Create a temp. Table like this, where the date is stored as varchar**

```
    CREATE TABLE `dateconv` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `datestr` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i3` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `i4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `i5` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=782 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**2) Insert all your data**

```
insert into dateconv values(781,'13-01-2005',10006,1,2.5,1,4.00);
...
insert into dateconv values(999,'13-01-2005',10006,1,2.5,1,4.00);
```

**3) you can select or insert the data in your destination table**

to show:

```
SELECT 
    id, STR_TO_DATE(datestr, "%d-%m-%Y"),
    i1,i2,i3,i4,i5
FROM dateconv;
```

to insert:

```
INSERT INTO jobs
SELECT 
    id, STR_TO_DATE(datestr, "%d-%m-%Y"),
    i1,i2,i3,i4,i5
FROM dateconv;
```

**alternativ way**

turn a function **STR_TO_DATE** around each datestring like this:

```
insert into jobs values(781,STR_TO_DATE('13-01-2005', "%d-%m-%Y"),10006,1,2.5,1,4.00);
```